# Passing array into bash function

Tags: bash

Is there a way to pass an array into function as a single argument?

I tried the following which didn't work:

```
arr=(a b c)
my_func $arr
```

and also

```
arr(a b c)
my_func ${arr[*]}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Passing `"${arr[@]}"` (@quickshiftin's answer) kind of works, but it's important to note that it doesn't pass an *array*, but the array's *elements as individual arguments*, accessible to the invoked functions as `$1`, `$2`, ...

This has the following implications:

- in the invoked function you have to reassemble the arguments back into an array yourself (though that's easy to do: `reassembledArray=( "$@" )`
- if the input array was sparse, i.e, its indices aren't contiguous, this information is lost.

The short of it: there's no way to *pass* arrays *as such*.

That said, if you're invoking a *function* rather than a *script*, your function will have access to all variables in the current shell, so you could simply *directly* access an array variable defined in the same shell before the function call.

Example:

```
my_func() {
  echo "Elements of arr:"
  for el in "${arr[@]}"; do echo "[$el]"; done
}

arr=(a b c)
my_func
```

Answer (score 1):

Call the function like this

```
 my_func "${arr[@]}"
```